# InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Driver [logs] not supported. Any guides on how to debug or identify the invalid exception?

Tags: laravel

Using laravel 6.20.28

i have an export module that saves an xslx file to storage folder in laravel and then sends an email to target address. is there a way to identify where can i start debugging?

here's the stack trace logs of the errors:

```
#0 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php(90): Illuminate\\Support\\Manager->createDriver()
#1 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php(94): Illuminate\\Support\\Manager->driver()
#2 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(799): Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Mail\\{closure}()
#3 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#4 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(785): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#5 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(629): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#6 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#7 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1245): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#8 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php(40): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->offsetGet()
#9 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(799): Illuminate\\Mail\\MailServiceProvider->Illuminate\\Mail\\{closure}()
#10 /var/www/html/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(681): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
```

.env file is now directing to smtp not logs

already used config:clear to refresh .env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i went and restart the supervisor and it worked. (to those who encountered the same issue)

didn't notice in docker that you need to restart the supervisor so that the config cache will also get the updated .env file

Answer (score 0):

How about this file config/mail.php ?

Comment: Hi! i have everything on env() to make sure it follows .env and so far its in smtp and with the proper credentials. this is actually working few weeks back. not sure why it errors that way now. tis why i ask if there's an actual way of checking what this error actually meant or how to identify where the cause is.